# Printing plots generated in a function using R Markdown in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, rstudio

I am trying to use the R-Markdown feature in R Studio where I was trying to print plots which are generated inside a function. This is a basic run down example of what I am trying to do.

````
**Test printing plots generated in a function**
================================================

``` {r  fig.width=8, fig.height=4, warning=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, dev='png', echo=FALSE, fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1:10),y=c(11:20),z=c(21:30),name=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
library(ggplot2)

ex <- function(data){

  plot(data[,1],data[,2])
  plot(data[,1],data[,3])
}

for (i in 1:10){
t1 <- rbind(i,ex(dat))
}
t1
```
````

Those testing this code, please make sure to save it as ".Rmd" file and then run the *knithtml()* in RStudio toolbar. This code above works absolutely fine with the kind of html output I desire. However when I replace the base plotting function by ggplot based code, I cannot get the *knithtml()* to produce the ggplot output of the 10 plots that I got like before. The base plot code above is now replaced by the following code

```
  p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=data[,1],y=data[,2]))
  p1 <- p1+geom_point()
  p1
```

Am I missing something very simple here.

VJ

Comment: What if you made a faceted plot and knit that?

Comment: Nope! As long as it is inside the function, it is not being printed. Also, I just tested that qplot() produces the desired output whereas ggplot does not. Can I not print a ggplot object generated inside a function, outside other than by using ggsave() to save it as a pdf e.g.

Comment: Inside `for` statement or in a function, you need `print` ggplot2 object explicitly, so try `print(p1)`.

Comment: @kohske is right, and that is R FAQ 7.22: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f Before using `knitr`/RStudio, check if the code runs as expected in R; if it runs in R but not in RStudio, it is probably our bug, otherwise you are likely to be careless somewhere.

Comment: @kohske  and Yihui -  An explicit print(p1) statement inside the function works both in knitr/Rstudio and R by itself. I always thought of ggplot object as something that does not need an explicit call to print.  Also, I noticed that I cannot specify x=data[,1] and y=data[,2] as it complains the objects of type closure are subsettable. cafe876 below states this problem too, once I changes the code to x=x and y=y along with the print inside the function, it works.

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems in your code:

1. ggplot doesn't recognize the data x and y data, bacause it works inside the data environment. You should give it the column names directly.
2. The code in yur loop doesn't make sense. You can't mix a plot with an index... (the reason it works with the base plot is through a side-effect) I've replaced it with the simple plot command.

The following will work:

````
**Test printing plots generated in a function**
================================================

``` {r  fig.width=8, fig.height=4, warning=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, dev='png', echo=FALSE, fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1:10),y=c(11:20),z=c(21:30),name=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
library(ggplot2)

ex <- function(data){
  p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x,y=y))
  p1 <- p1+geom_point()
  return(p1) 
}

for (i in 1:2){
plot(ex(dat))
}

```
````

Comment: Thanks for the fix. The only reason I have an index with the plotting function is to return a different object from a function (like a summary table) along with generating the plots. I am sure there are better ways of doing this, but this seemed to work for me. Also, I wonder why R would not complain the need to required variables (x,y) when using the plot() command in the for loop. I tried with print and it worked fine. Thanks anyways.